# get the list of exception codes

Tags: php, exception, symfony

Working with Symfony 2, I created an exception event listener to catch my exceptions. It works good and inside of it I get the code of the exception like this :

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $code = $exception->getCode()
    ....
}
```

For example, the exception I catch is a problem in a twig template. a variable does not exist.

The code of the exception is 0.

What does that mean ?

Where can I find a list of the different codes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception code `0` is the default code in PHP. You can see it in the [`\Exception` constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/exception.construct.php).

Main of Symfony Exception have their code to zero because it's not overriden. And it's very difficult to get a complete list of all excetions' codes.

However, concerning your custom exceptions, that you created in your application, you can set their codes with values you want and handle them in your Event Listener.

For example, you could have something like :

```
class ResourceNotFoundException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = '')
    {
        return parent::__construct($message, 404);
    }
}
```

As a result, your exception's code for this exception will be `404`. Now your application design and the traitment you want to do in your event listener will guide you in you devlepment.